# How to convert this variables in to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, xml, arraylist

I'm totally new to javascript and below is my question,  I have a for each loop which assign some variables and pass it in to other functions;

```
$scope.kmIds.forEach(function (kendra, index) {
    {
        var params = {
            fromdate: $scope.dateFrom,
            todate: $scope.dateTo,
            kendraId: kendra.recordId

        };
count++; 
SomeFunctionXYZ (params, function (error, data) )
    }
```

Here I need the fromdate, todate and kendraId to be wrapped in a array and feed that as  params in to  SomeFunctionXYZ.

I tried this

```
$scope.kmIds.forEach(function (kendra, index) {
    {
        var params = {
            fromdate: $scope.dateFrom,
            todate: $scope.dateTo,
            kendraId: kendra.recordId

        };
var result = Object.keys(params).map (function(key) {
result.push(params[key]);
});
count++;
SomeFunctionXYZ (params, function (error, data) )
    }

But I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
please advice.
```

Comment: _"I'm totally new to javascript"_ - Then you should get a tutorial on how to work with objects and how to work with arrays. Getting the properties (their values) into an array shouldn't be that complicated after that.

Comment: If this is Angularjs, you should probably add that to the tag list.

Answer (score 0):

To move an item to an array in the map function, you only need to return the value that you want to push.

```
var result = Object.keys(params).map (function(key) {
    return params[key];
});
```